# Why does Windows have to visit every file to turn off indexing

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, search-indexing

I have just turned off indexing for a *removable* hard drive under Windows 10, *(surely this should be a simple flag)*, and the machine has spent the last hour apparently accessing what looks like every single file on this, *(2Tb),* hard drive.

This seemed to include all sorts of file types, i.e. doc, docx, jpeg, png, svg, exe, dll, zip - it seemed very indiscriminate.  Of course while this was happening I felt it was unsafe to switch off the drive.

Can anybody explain why this is necessary?  Surely if the files have already been indexed it would be much quicker to simply, *in background,* scan the index for any entries that referred to this drive and remove them rather than going to every single file or at least just set an exclude flag in each directory.

Comment: The index flag for each file entry in the MFT needs to be changed.  It's not visiting each file physically, just its metadata in the MFT.

Comment: Files may have indexing attributes. Remove that attributes with `attrib /s /d *.* -I` command. See this:: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266513(v=vs.85).aspx